# How to import an object into an Armory game scene while the game is running?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, objects, armory

How can one import an object (an *obj*) in an Armory game while the game is running? For example, I want to import an object (*car.obj*) when I press a key and remove that object if I press another key. I wonder how this would be possible using a Haxe script or a logic node set up?

In case it is not possible to import an *obj* file directly into the scene I don’t mind converting the objects to another format that Armory supports. I just need to be able to import my objects into the game environment and remove them. Is that possible?

The closest things I found are [this](https://github.com/armory3d/armory_examples/tree/master/script_linkedgroup) and [this](https://github.com/armory3d/armory_examples/tree/master/script_spawnobject) Armory example scripts but they do not import objects that are stored on disk. For my work, I need to be able to dynamically manipulate objects, store them on disk and load them into the game and these scripts seem to not be helpful for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean add an object into the scene, you use the import. Click file in the top right, hover over import, and click wavefront for an OBJ, Then import what you want to. If you mean have it go into the game at a certain point, that'd take other scripts. I don't really know what you mean by a game, I assume you're making a game.

Comment: I know how to import objects in Blender itself but I'm using Armory and its different.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what you're talking about, sorry.

Comment: @ARobloxPlayer25 FYI https://armory3d.org/